# Как добавить дополнительные ipv6 адреса?

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

Имеется сервер на Ubuntu и ipv6-подсеть от tunnelbroker.net. В `/etc/network/interfaces` прописал:

```
auto he-ipv6  
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel  
 address 2001:XXXX:a8b::2  
 netmask 64  
 endpoint 216.XXXX.30  
 local 185.XXXXX.112  
 ttl 255  
 gateway 2001:XXXXX:a8b::1
```

На сервере появился один ipv6-адресс. Вопрос: как добавить дополнительные ipv6-адреса из выделенной подсети?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

как и обычно — добавить в секцию `iface` директиву `up`, в которой можно указать команду, которая будет выполнена после поднятия интерфейса:

```
up ip a a 2001:XXXX:a8b::3/64 dev $IFACE
```

приведённая команда `ip ...` добавит к интерфейсу адрес `2001:XXXX:a8b::3/64`.

вместо переменной `IFACE` будет подставлено имя интерфейса, в секции которого находится данная директива `up` (т.е., в вашем случае, будет подставлена строка `he-ipv6`).

---

p.s. таких директив может быть много. что позволит добавить любое количество ip-адресов.

Comment: Не выходит. Добавил в конце блока  up ip addr add 2001:4xx:a8b::15/64 dev he-ipv6. После перезагрузки в ifconfig виден только основной ip адрес.

Comment: ifconfig [не стоит использовать (как минимум для диагностики, а лучше вообще)](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=129712). смотрите адреса командой `ip a`.