# 2 IP адреса на одном сервере Debian

Tags: сервер, debian, сеть, ip

У меня есть свой сервер на debian. У меня был 1 ip адрес, теперь я купил еще 1 и хочу, что бы по нему тоже открывался мой севрер. Гуглил, ничего не подошло. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: 1. поднять этот адрес на сервере (алиасом на интерфейсе или еще как нибудь, есть разные варианты). 2. Прописать данный адрес в DNS для вашего доменного имени

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525422/178576

Comment: я не очень в этом разбираюсь, мне нужно что бы по 2-му адресу открывался сервер

Answer (score 3):

В `/etc/network/interfaces` пишешь

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.1.3
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:1
allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

IP адреса естественно свои, а дальше запись в DNS и маршрутизация.

Comment: по-моему, ответ честно заслужил «минус». (не от меня, конечно: я с прошлого года «минусов» не ставлю).

Comment: делал, не помогло

Comment: @Diefair а `service networking restart` (ну или ребут сервера) потом делал?